# Import csv files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I'm trying to import a [csv file](http://mathpr.com/data_matlab.csv) (7816 x 119) with a lot of tiny numbers (between 1.0E-11 and 1.0E-9) using the following code:

```
filename = 'dataset.csv';   
D = importdata(filename,',',1);
```

When I check the import result I obtain

```
D= 
data: [187x119 double]
textdata: {1x119 cell}
colheaders: {1x119 cell}
```

Note that the size of `D` is a lot smaller than the original data size.

When I do the same process with a matrix with bigger numbers (not scientific notation) I don't have any problem.

I'm wondering if MATLAB have a restriction of size that I can import in a csv file or restrictions with numbers in scientific notation?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Strip down your data until it works, figure out why it works now. I guess your data is somewhere corrupt. How are the tiny numbers represented? Scientific notation?

Comment: @pschulz I already do that but can't find the error. The numbers are represented in scientific notation. The data file is [CSV data file](http://mathpr.com/data_matlab.csv).

Comment: It still works fine for me with the data you provided. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @pschulz Which version of matlab are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As is suspected, your data is corrupted in some places. Search for 'DIV' in the file, you will find an entry '#DIV/0!' several times. Interestingly, this worked in some matlab version for me (i currently don't know the version number) as well as it works in octave with a current release.

Here the test:

```
D = csvread('data_matlab.csv', 1, 0);
```

gives

```
Error using dlmread (line 143)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 187, field number 72) ==>
#DIV/0!,1.11E-08,0,9.28E-09,2.8E-09,0.000000031,1.99E-08,6.49E-10,1.75E-09,9.66E-09,8.47E-10,3.82E-09,2.41E-10,1.71E-09,5.48E-09,1.32E-09,8.73E-09,2.05E-09,8.89E-10,3.83E-10,0,1.36E-08,2.92E-09,3.08E-...

Error in csvread (line 47)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

Where do you get the data from? Can you influence the output? If you can't replace the errorneous entries by hand (using an appropriate tool) or use @Trogdors answer.

Comment: Well done! I double checked and the problem still exists with Matlab 2016b-64.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the problem. Using `xlsread` did not produce that issue:

```
filename = 'data_matlab.csv';
d = xlsread(filename);
```

Comment: Which Version of matlab are you using? Did you use the provided data? This is strange, i cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was with 2015b 32 bit. I also have 2016b 64, so I can check on that one.

Comment: @Trogdor Please let me know if you obtain the same error in 2016b 64. In mi case, I'm using 2015a 64.

Comment: Ah, i was now able to replicate the error, it worked for me before, but not at home, where i'm using a different matlab version. I don't know the version at university, sorry.